# DialogueTrigger.Text is a field, but a type was expected+

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a dialogue system in unity, in which a player would walk up to an NPC and press E to trigger a dialogue response, However, when I attempt to access the "Text" Component of the GameObject, I receive two of the same errors:

Assets/DialogueTrigger.cs(28,24): error CS0118: `DialogueTrigger.Text is a` field' but a `type' was expected

This is the component I am trying to access:
[Text (Script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrbSW.png)

The component is in This game object:
[Game Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIAGH.png)

Here is the code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public string Text;
    public string Name;
    public GameObject Dialog;
    public GameObject Texta;
    public GameObject Namea;
    public Collider2D collision;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision col)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Dialog.SetActive(true);
                Texta.GetComponent<Text>().Text = "Hello!";
                Namea.GetComponent<Text>().Text = "Guy";
            }
        }
}
```

Any solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a field named `Text` which is being used as the GetComponents generic type.  I suggest following the C# naming conventions, keeping fields lower case, Types and methods uppercase.  Or you can specify that the Text you are talking about is `UnityEngine.UI.Text`, and not the class field Text

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, but another error appears if i use this, Assets/DialogueTrigger.cs(4,1): error CS0138: A `using' directive can only be applied to namespaces but `UnityEngine.UI.Text' denotes a type. Consider using a `using static' instead

Comment: Not sure how you wrote the using statement.  To be clear, it should look like `Texta.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>()`.  I really do suggest following the naming conventions though, since that is how it is suggested by Microsoft and is more familiar to all C# coders.  [Coding Conventions C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

There's a name conflict between your field named 'Text' and the component type 'Text', so the compiler doesn't understand which one you meant by GetComponent<Text>().

You can resolve this by changing the name of your field to something else, like for example 'text'.

You also don't even need to call GetComponent<Text>() if you change the types of your Texta and Namea fields to Text.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public string Text;
    public string Name;
    public GameObject Dialog;
    public Text Texta;
    public Text Namea;
    public Collider2D collision;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision col)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Dialog.SetActive(true);
            Texta.text = "Hello!";
            Namea.text = "Guy";
        }
    }
}
```